# Sybase ASE 12.5.2 server config error 208

Tags: sap-ase

We have a sybase ASE server and recently, when we try to open the server config, and after logging in, we are facing an error with

> message number 208, sysconfigures not found. Specify owner.objectname
>   or use sp_help to check whether the object exists.

We have verified that the table exists in master database. Also did consistency check and ensured that the owner is dbo. Database owner for master is also sa. Anybody faced this issue?
ASA version: Adaptive Server Enterprise/12.5.3/EBF 13331 ESD#7/P/NT (IX86)/OS 4.0/ase1253/1951/32-bit/OPT.
Screenshot as below:
[image: Sybase Server Config Error]

TIA 
Arfath